# Series R-L AC Circuit Analysis - Conditional

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

Is there a way to get resistance and inductance of a circuit wherein the only given is the source,circuit current and its frequency?

To make it clear, ill give an example:

An impedance coil takes a 3A and connected across 110V 60Hz source. But then the impedance coil is connected across 220V 25Hz source and takes 4A. Find the resistance and the inductance of the coil?

Im getting confused... What will I solve first? What i know is that at first I can get is the impedance of the circuit, and im stuck there, dont know what will solve next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to know the circuit current in the second case (220V, 25Hz), otherwise you have 2 equations and three unknown values, such as:

- Resistance (R)
- Inductance (L)
- Circuit current in 2nd case (I2)

The equations are:

V1 = R*I1 + j*w1*L*I1

V2 = R*I2 + j*w2*L*I2

Comment: Ohh i forgot,  there is a given value for the current in the second case.

Comment: In case you have I2 value, here above you have the 2 equations you need to solve to calculate R and L. You can also calculate the impedances Z1 and Z2 (V/I) and then solve a system of 2 equations, if you want to avoid complex numbers.